# How to apply triple level of condition in an XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, expression, multi-level

Here is the XML that I have have from Zoho CRM and I need to get the Email where the record is of the primary contact:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?-->
  <response uri="/crm/private/xml/Contacts/getRelatedRecords">
     <result>
       <contacts>
        <row no="1">
           <fl val="CONTACTID">511618000000889989</fl>
           <fl val="Email">
               <!--[CDATA[person1@example.com]]-->
           </fl>
           <fl val="Primary">
               <!--[CDATA[true]]-->
           </fl>
        </row>
        <row no="2">
           <fl val="CONTACTID">511617845475451213</fl>
           <fl val="Email">
              <!--[CDATA[person2@example.com]]-->
           </fl>
           <fl val="Primary">
              <!--[CDATA[false]]-->
           </fl>
        </row>
       </contacts>
     </result>
  </response>
```

In the above case the xpath expression should return person1@example.com as the email of the person who is a Primary.

I started off writing the expression as:

```
/response/result/contacts/row[./fl/@val='Primary' and ]/fl[@val='Email']/text()
```

but can't get past the point of writing a combined predicate for the row element.

**Another problem is the namespace. Seems like this XML has a namespace. How to deal with namespaces in the XPATH in this case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CDATA sections shouldn't be written as comment.
Assuming you replace

```
<!--[CDATA[true]]-->
```

with

```
<![CDATA[true]]>
```

You could get your addresses with

```
//row[fl[@val="Primary" and matches(text(),"true")]]/fl[@val="Email"]/text()
```

If now you don't have control over the generation of your CDATA, and want to treat them as comment, go for

```
//row[fl[@val="Primary" and matches(comment(),"true")]]/fl[@val="Email"]/substring-before(substring-after(comment(),"CDATA["),"]]")
```

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason it cannot parse the matches function. Do I need to give a certain system namespace or is a function execution related to a certain level of implementation parser implementation?

Comment: If it doesn't recognize matches() it means you're using XPath 1.0. In this case, replace matches() with contains().
But you will not be able to use any function at the location step, you will have to extract your email value in a second step.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by two steps? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: What I mean is that the xpath expression will return you the CDATA field, enclosed into the brackets, for example [CDATA[person2@example.com]].
You will need to extract the email address with the code calling the xpath expression.

Comment: Superb! It worked like a charm @A Hocevar. Thanks for your help. This works in .Net but the Zoho Parser still has a problem. I think the XPATH is correct, seems to be a problem with the parser used by ZOHO.

Answer (score 1):

will this work?

```
//fl[@val='Primary' and contains(text(), 'true')]//preceding-sibling::fl[@val='Email']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the real XML does not have these two nodes next to each other. Thanks for your input. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those `CDATA` sections actually *are* CDATA sections and not comments, this should do it:

```
/response/result/contacts/row[normalize-space(fl[@val = 'Primary]) = 'true']
                             /fl[@val = 'Email']
```

As far as I can tell, your XML doesn't use a namespace.  The `uri=` is just an ordinary attribute.

Comment: Have no control over the XML generation as it comes from an external system. Thanks four input though.